# Colorize the background of a seaborn plot using a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph, seaborn

## Question

How to shade or colorize the *background* of a [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) plot using a column of a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)?

## Code snippet

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
fmri.sort_values('timepoint',inplace=True)
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", data=fmri)
arr = np.ones(len(fmri))
arr[:300] = 0
arr[600:] = 2
fmri['background'] = arr

ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event", data=fmri)
```

Which produced this graph:
[image: Actual output]

## Desired output

What I'd like to have, according to the value in the new column `'background'` and any [palette](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) or user defined [colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors), something like this:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: But the `background` values seem to spread all over `timepoint`. How do you decide which part comes first/last?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I didn't took the time to correctly look at the data actually. It should be fixed now. Thanks for having point it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ax.axvspan()` could work for you, assuming backgrounds don't overlap over timepoints.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
fmri.sort_values('timepoint',inplace=True)
arr = np.ones(len(fmri))
arr[:300] = 0
arr[600:] = 2
fmri['background'] = arr
fmri['background'] = fmri['background'].astype(int).astype(str).map(lambda x: 'C'+x)

ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event", data=fmri)
ranges = fmri.groupby('background')['timepoint'].agg(['min', 'max'])
for i, row in ranges.iterrows():
    ax.axvspan(xmin=row['min'], xmax=row['max'], facecolor=i, alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Why does a third line pop out on the graph? ;-)

Comment: Oops! I included two plots!  This line should be dropped: `ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", data=fmri)`

Comment: How would this work for multiple facets, like with relplot or other FacetGrid options in seaborn?

Comment: I think the `.map()` or `.map_dataframe()` methods of FacetGrid objects coulp help. In the documentation there are examples of these methods. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html