# Adding background color based on column value to seaborn facetgrid plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm plotting some data and am trying to find a way to apply background color to a line plot depending on the value of a feature.

Let's say I have a df like this

```
x  y     col background_color
1  0.34  16  a
2  0.45  14  b
3  0.90  1   none
4  0.003 7   b
5  0.41  14  a
6  0.34  16  b
7  0.45  14  a
8  0.90  1   a
9  0.003 7   b
10 0.41  14  a
..........
```

Currently my plot set up would be something like:

```
sns.relplot(x="x", y="y", col="col", col_wrap=1, kind="line", legend="full", ci=None, data=df)
```

I've worked with things like plt.axvline before, but only to put in a single line here or there with a manual assignment - meaning `plt.axvline(3, color='r')`. 
Is there a way to do this dynamically, based on the value of a column so that there is a different color for each value of `background_color`?

edit: If a FacetGrid is not the best way to go about this, I'm open to other suggestions. FacetGrid is my go-to for multi-pane vizes like this.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60887648/colorize-the-background-of-a-seaborn-plot-using-a-column-in-dataframe?

Comment: @Alex - sort of, except `axvspan` doesn't seem to work for facetgrid style plots.